# How do I use the X and Y values from an object from touches in P5js?

Tags: p5.js

This is my first week playing with P5js and Processing so **be gentle.**

I've got the following P5js code where I'm looking at touch values. By pressing multi-points on a touch screen brings up more circles anchored to a central position.

What I'd like to know is how do I call the x value for object 1 that's printed in the console? or y value for object 0? how would i state them in the code?

What I'd like to do is use these values to change the dimensions of a shape in the middle of the screen, like something in object 0 driving the height of the shape or object 1 on the the x or y values driving strokeWeight or colour . However I'm in my first week and completely lost to how to use these values in the code.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(200);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(0)

  for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
    fill(255);
    strokeWeight(3)
    ellipse(touches[i].x, touches[i].y, 50, 50);
    line(touches[i].x, touches[i].y, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);



    fill(255);
    ellipse(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 10, 10);
    print(touches);
  }
}

// do this prevent default touch interaction
function mousePressed() {
  return false;
}

document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[or Sketch file is here](https://editor.p5js.org/joshuaebutters/sketches/-b-tahz9r)

**any help would be muchly muchly appreciated, i'm a newb trying to find my way**

Comment: Just FYI, the `processing` tag should be reserved to questions regarding the native Java version of Processing, and it's not necessary to tag basic programming concepts like `object` and `array`. Just `p5.js` will suffice for a question like this.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are asking. From the code you've posted it looks like you basic understanding of how `touches` works. To answer one of your specific questions "how do I call the x value for object 1 that's printed in the console?" the answer is quite trivial: `touches[1].x`. However I'm not sure how helpful that is.

Comment: This question was cross posted on the processing discourse forum: https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-do-i-use-the-x-and-y-values-from-an-object-from-touches-in-p5js/31766/3

Comment: Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question properly to help understand it better

Answer (score 0):

There is only one mistake in it which I found till now, the color of the background and the fill colors are the same! you may change them to actually see the shapes, lines etc.